# Recyclerview lag on scroll due to Admob ads

Tags: android, admob, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I want to load ads in RecyclerView ads are loaded successfully but it is casuing so much lag while scrolling

Following is code I have written in **OnBindViewHolder** method of Adapter

How to fix this lag?

```
((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(((DealHolder) holder).itemView.getContext());
                    final int adWidth = ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getWidth() - ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getPaddingLeft()
                            - ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getPaddingRight();
                    final int adHeight = ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getHeight() - ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getPaddingBottom()
                            - ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getPaddingTop();
                    final float scale = ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), (int) (adHeight / scale));
                    adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                    adView.setAdUnitId(((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.getContext().getString(R.string.test_adunit_id));
                    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("jjhjhbjhjhjhjhjhjhjh").build();
                    adView.loadAd(request);
                    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded() {
                            super.onAdLoaded();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                        }
                    });
                    ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.removeAllViews();
                    ((DealHolder) holder).adcardView.addView(adView);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Use [systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html) to understand on what operation exactly you are wasting time.

Comment: An additional advice. You are casting your holder everytime you use. Cast it once and hold it in DealHolder variable.

Answer (score 10):

Improvements :

1. Do not try to load your Adview when the user is trying to scroll. To do that make your adapter recylerView scroll aware and then check whether the 
   `scroll_state==RecylerView.Scroll_IDLE`, then only load your AdView.
2. If all your adViews have same width and height do not calculate it every time user scrolls, cache it in a variable.
3. Instead of dynamically adding and removing your NativeExpressAdView, use a XML version for it in your item_view. You can hide and show based on conditions. Set all the possible required attributes in XML view.

Comment: One point three I am using cardview and ad is not displayed if I use xml version it is working dynamically only by calculating left right padding

Comment: @apk I will try to come up with one.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new AdView for each view holder would be quite Resource hungry.

Instead of creating new adview on each view holder inflate adview after a certain interval like e.g after every 5 or 10 items.

- Create two different layouts to use in adapter one with ads and another without ads.
- Override getItemViewType() method

`public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position % 10 == 0){ // Ad after every 10 items
            return 0; //use integer constant to identify view type is Adview.
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }`

- in OnCreateViewHolder() method

  `@Override
  public ViewHolderClass onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  if (viewType == 0){ // Constant for Adview
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_row_with_ads, parent,false);
      return new ViewHolderClass(view, viewType);
  }
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_row, parent,false);
  return new ViewHolderClass(view);
  }`
- In your ViewholderClass create a second Constructor with parameters View and int

  `public class ViewHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       ...
       public ViewHolderClass(View view){
           ...
       }
       public ViewHolderClass(View view, int viewType){
           ...
           // Initialize your adview here
       }`
- For your layouts. If your adapter_row.xml is like this :

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:id="@+id/base"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>         // your main content
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

- Then create another layout file for adapter adapter_row_with_ads.xml with these changes.

> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:id="@+id/base"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>         // your main content
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>
>       <!--This is where you'll add your AdView-->
>       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
>           android:id="@+id/adView"
>           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:layout_below="@id/base"/>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

This approach will reduce battery drainage and resource consumption and your app will be smoother

Comment: how can I caluculate height and width I am using cardview

Comment: you could define it easily in xml in the layout file adapter_row_with_ads.xml